# Missing icons in terminal, it shows squares with numbers into

Tags: icons, gnome-terminal, fonts

I am working on a CLI application that normally shows icons at every beginning of terminal rows. There are some icons at every row beginning, sometime animated when the app is working. I don't know why my terminal shows squares, with numbers inside, instead of icons.

[image: Little animated icons at beginning of the raws]

Comment: A lot more information is needed starting with Ubuntu version, what is the "app", etc.

Comment: Please upload a screenshot of a word processor document that shows what the expected icons look like. Maybe the Unicode used in the terminal does not support the Unicode subset which contains these missing icons.

Answer (score 0):

This is the terminal. I solved installing some fonts. I don't remember what font I installed but I remember that I deleted them before. Durin a cleaning of the system I have deleted some fonts. Reinstalling some system fonts I noticed that icons was reactivated.

[image: Terminal screenshot]

Comment: You had probably removed the Noto Emoji font.